# How can I create an alias for cd and ls?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I frequently run the `ls` command after running the `cd` command. How can I create an alias (like `cs`) for this operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks [Florian Diesch](https://askubuntu.com/users/2369/florian-diesch) for the tip of using a function. I can't use `cs` as the name because there is a `cs` command in the [csound](http://packages.ubuntu.com/p/csound) package, so I used `lc`.

I added this to `~/.bash_aliases` (`nano ~/.bash_aliases`):

```
function lc () {
    cd $1;
    ls 
}
```

The terminal needs to be `reset` for this to come into effect.

Comment: Having `$1` unquoted like that will make it fail if the directory contains whitespace. Also, you should check the return value of `cd`; if it failed (e.g. permission denied), there's no point in running the `ls`. `lc() { cd "$@" && ls; }`

Answer (score 38):

From [Bash Tips and Tricks: 'cd' with style](http://www.talug.org/events/20030813/cmdline_tips_n_tricks_aug03.html):

> Finally, I want to show you how to write your own custom replacement for the 'cd' command.
>
> Do you find yourself always typing the same thing upon changing into a directory? You probably at least list the files there every time, perhaps so much that your hands automatically type 'ls' after every 'cd'.
>
> Well, by trying every way I could think of, it turns out there's only one way to properly accomplish the goal we're seeking. We have to create a shell function.
>
> Shell functions are part of shell programming. Like in compiled programming languages, functions provide a sort of procedural modularizability. One can create a generic function to perform an often-used bit of logic or computation with different parameters. In this case, the parameter is the current working directory.
>
> Here's a simple one:
>
> ```
> function cs () {
>     cd $1
>     ls
> }
> ```

As [@geirha](https://askubuntu.com/users/9016) corretly notes, the above function will fail if you try to switch to a directory with a space in its name:

```
$ cs A\ B/
-bash: cd: A: No such file or directory
<current directory listing>
```

You should instead use the following function:

```
function cs () {
    cd "$@" && ls
    }
```

Once you add that code to your `~/.bashrc`, you should be able to do this:

```
hello@world:~$ cs Documents/
example.pdf tunafish.odt
hello@world:~/Documents$
```

Comment: That'll fail for directories containing whitespace. See the comment to dv3500ea's answer.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the [`builtin`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) command in bash :

```
function cd() {
    new_directory="$*";
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then 
        new_directory=${HOME};
    fi;
    builtin cd "${new_directory}" && ls
}
```

Comment: This is pretty slick. I had a solution similar to @Florian in my .bashrc for a very long time, but this is much more satisfactory for when I forget that colleagues don't have my 'cs' alias on their computers.

Comment: I like this answer the best. For some reason, you can't use aliases to overwrite the command, so you have to make a function like this answer. :D

Comment: But what about non-builtin commands? For example, the above won't work for overwriting the ls command. Is there some keyword to use instead of "builtin"?

Comment: use the full path for it, example : `function ls() { /usr/bin/ls $* }`

Comment: I had problems redefining `cd` because `rvm` changes my `cd` definition too. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19941991/1601989

Answer (score 17):

Use a function instead of an alias:

```
cs() { cd "$1" && ls; }
```

Comment: +1, as this version will stop if 'cd' fails.

Answer (score 1):

As an expansion to this function: `cs() { cd "$1" && ls; }`, you may want to pass all of the function's arguments to `cd` by using `$@` instead of `"$1"` as such: `cs() { cd $@ && ls; }`.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems redefining `cd` because `rvm` changes my `cd` definition too. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19941991/1601989. I didn't really want to use `builtin` because that would skip whatever `rvm` is doing.

I added the following to my `.bashrc`:

```
# cdd allows you to cd to the directory of the given file or directory
function cdd()
{
  if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    cd
  elif [[ -d "$*" ]]; then
    cd "$*"
  elif [[ -f "$*" ]]; then
    echo "WARNING: file given, cd to file's dirname" 1>&2
    local dir=$(dirname "$*")
    cd "$dir"
  else
    cd "$*"
  fi
}

function cs()
{
  cdd $* && ls
}
```

And then after the `rmv` line in the `.bashrc`:

```
alias cd='cdd'
# Use bash built in completion for cd to allow for filenames to be used
complete -r cd
```