# Alias cd and ls with support for spaces and arguments

Tags: command-line, bash

So I started with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16106/how-can-i-create-an-alias-for-cd-and-ls) discussion, and it basically does exactly what I want.

However, the solution to preserve directory whitespace using quotes fails when using arguments, e.g. `cd -P dir`. Any ideas for preserving whitespace and allowing for option flags?

This is the function I'm currently using.

```
function cd {
    new_directory="$*";
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then 
        new_directory=${HOME};
    fi;
    builtin cd "${new_directory}" && ls;
}
```

For example, with the above, `cd -P My\ Documents/` becomes `cd "-P My Documents"` which obviously fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `$*`, you've lost: this erases the distinction between spaces in an argument and spaces to separate arguments. Use `"$@"` instead, which expands to one word per argument.

```
function cd {
  builtin cd "$@" && ls
}
```

Comment: Same issue. For example, from 'cd My\ Documents/', $* and $@ produce 'My Documents/', losing the backslash that's needed if you don't have quotes.

Comment: `"$@"`. It looks like you left out the quotes.

Comment: Ah, you're right, that works perfectly. Thank you very much.